# Design a service to calculate the top k listened to songs in past 24 hrs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, database-design, system-design

This is a system design question.

Assume we have a service that can notify us when a song is listened to. Let's design a new service that is capable of returning the top K most listened to songs in the past 24 hours. Assume we have ~1 billion songs and ~200 million users.

Focus your answer around caching, data structures, and the design of your database schema.

Follow up: How can we separate it out by genre? E.g. what if I want the top k most listened to rock songs in the last 24 hrs?

Really just curious what you guys would say / what you guys think! Don't have to give a super perfect solution, ideas are great as well.

Comment: How about using a max heap? Solution time complexity would be around k log (n) where `n` is number of songs.

Comment: How do you ensure that the max heap only stores data for the last 24 hours? You would have to do some sort of pruning to constantly remove song counts are more than 24 hours old, right? How would that work?

Comment: Perhaps we create a new max heap every 24 hours? Problem is then if someone asks for the top songs right after the heap gets created for that day, they wont get much of a result back. Maybe we would take yesterday's results at that point since the heap is complete. Then your results are always 1 day old though

Comment: If the heap gets created for that day, why can't we return them?

Comment: Let's say we create a new (empty) heap at 12AM every day. Then for the next 24 hours we collect the data we need for that day. What happens if someone requests the top songs at 1AM, right after the new heap is created? Then you would only get the top songs requested for the last hour. If you return yesterday's heap, then your results are off and do not include the last hour

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to get the top k listened songs

You should consider the Misra Gries Algorithm [Misra gries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misra-Gries_summary)

It keep array of k elements and their estimated values, what matters for you is that It keeps the most frequent k elements in the stream (your notified songs list)

Answer (score 0):

This typically looks like recommendation system design.

[Recommender systems](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/datastructures.html)

You can simply think of heap algorithm using maxheap to retrieve last k elements and enhance by building complex constraints.